# No text shown, only captcha lines are visible

Tags: php

PHP code:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['secure'];
header('content-type:image/png');
$text="hello";
$font_size=25;
$width=200;
$height=200;
$image=imagecreate($width, $height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
for($x=1; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    $x1 = rand(1, 100);
    $y1 = rand(1, 100);
    $x2 = rand(1, 100);
    $y2 = rand(1, 100);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $black);
}
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $black, 'consolas.ttf', $text);
$imgSrc="out.png";
imagejpeg($image, $imgSrc);
?>
```

When the image is generated, only lines are drawn but text("hello") is not drawn on it. 
The font is also in the same directory, I have also kept it in another directory and added the complete path no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm debugging this issue and found that font file is not accessible.

I have checked by turning on debugging as below:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

And commented lines below.

```
header('content-type:image/png');


imagepng($image);
```

Got error:

> Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 24

**Soultion:**

Path to font file should be realpath on server. So the code should be:

```
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $black, realpath('consolas.ttf'), $text);
```

Also change in render image without giving `$imgSrc` and changing it to

```
imagepng($image);
```

instead of

```
$imgSrc="out.png";
imagejpeg($image, $imgSrc);
```

Finally complete code will look like:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['secure'];
header('content-type:image/png');
$text = "hello";
$font_size = 25;
$width = 200;
$height = 200;
$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
for ($x = 1; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    $x1 = rand(1, 100);
    $y1 = rand(1, 100);
    $x2 = rand(1, 100);
    $y2 = rand(1, 100);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $black);
}
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $black, realpath('Consolas.ttf'), $text);
imagepng($image);
```